# Angular 4 application performance issue

Tags: node.js, angular, socket.io, bing-maps

I have developed Angular 4 application using BingMap and NodeJs(socket.io).
On bing map I am showing data which are coming continuously through socket.io.
Basically I am showing moving car on map based on data I receive through socket.io from messaging server.

I am facing performance issue in IE and FireFox. It becomes too heavy after a minutes.

The issue happened when I do zoom-in, zoom-out and drag the map to change the location.

**I won't post the code because of policy but any direction to optimize the performance will help me.

Any advice or help would be appreciated!!

Thanks,
Pushkar

Comment: It's not possible for us to give you very high quality help without detailed information. At most we could recommend some simple optimizations,

Comment: I can't post the code because of policy and what kind of detailed information you need @MustacheMoses ?

Answer (score 0):

Every time you add or update data on the map, the map canvas is re-rendered. If you have a continuous flow of data being updated/loaded on the map the map will constantly being re-rendered which will cause a performance issue. Try updating/loading data in batches (i.e. once every 2 seconds).